# Is it sourced that Avrohom Avinu charged his guests payment if they did not make a Brachah?

Tags: vayera, abraham

The Gemara in Soitah (10a I think) says that Avrohom used to tell people not to thank him, but rather to thank Hashem for the food that they ate.

I seem to remember learning once that if they refused, they had to pay him for the food that they ate, I dont know if this is true or not.

Does anyone know a source to this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Shita Mekubetzet to Sotah 10b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.10b.1?lang=bi&p2=Shita_Mekubetzet_on_Sotah.10b.1&lang2=bi) brings exactly what you are remembering in the name of midrash.

> **והודו ושבחו וברכו למי שאמר והיה העולם.** יש במדרש שלא רצו לברך ברצונם עד *שאמר להם אברהם אבינו פרעו מה שאכלתם ושתיתם והיה אומר שעולה לממון גדול* לפי שהיו במדבר והיה טורח גדול להם להביא לשם המאכל והמשקה.

The midrash is brought in full by [Torah Sheleimah](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51454&pgnum=138) to Genesis 21:33 § 136 from [Midrash Aggadah](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Aggadah,_Genesis.21.33.3).

Comment: Thanks for the additional citation @robev

Answer (score 11):

Midrash Rabbah 49:7 ([Sefaria Link](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.49.3-4?lang=bi&with=Midrash&lang2=en)) ([Hebrewbooks.org Link](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&pgnum=117)) brings the story in full, including the details about the exorbitant prices Avraham would charge, since he was located in the desert.

> כִּי יְדַעְתִּיו לְמַעַן אֲשֶׁר יְצַוֶּה (בראשית יח, יט), רַבִּי יוּדָן בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי אֲלֶכְּסַנְדְּרִי זוֹ הוֹבְרָיָא. וְרַבָּנָן אָמְרֵי זוֹ בִּקּוּר חוֹלִים. רַבִּי עֲזַרְיָה בְּשֵׁם רַבִּי יְהוּדָה מִתְּחִלָּה צֶדֶק לְבַסּוֹף מִשְׁפָּט. הָא כֵּיצַד אַבְרָהָם הָיָה מְקַבֵּל אֶת הָעוֹבְרִים וְאֶת הַשָּׁבִים, מִשֶּׁהָיוּ אוֹכְלִים וְשׁוֹתִים אָמַר לָהֶם בָּרֵכוּ. אָמְרוּ לוֹ מַה נֹּאמַר, אָמַר לָהֶם אִמְרוּ בָּרוּךְ אֵל עוֹלָם שֶׁאָכַלְנוּ מִשֶּׁלּוֹ, אִם מְקַבֵּל עָלָיו וּבְרִיךְ, הֲוָה אָכֵיל וְשָׁתֵי וְאָזֵיל, וְאִי לָא הֲוָה מְקַבֵּל עֲלֵיהּ וּבָרִיךְ, הֲוָה אֲמַר לֵיהּ הַב מַה דַּעֲלָךְ. וְאָמַר מָה אִית לָךְ עָלַי, הֲוָה אֲמַר לֵיהּ, חַד קְסִיט דַּחֲמַר בַּעֲשָׂרָה פּוֹלָרִין, וְחַד לִיטְרָא דְּקוֹפָר בַּעֲשָׂרָה פוֹלָרִין, וְחַד עִגּוּל דְּרִפְתָּא בַּעֲשָׂרָה פוֹלָרִין. מַאן יָהֵיב לָךְ חַמְרָא בְּמַדְבְּרָא, מַאי יָהֵיב לָךְ קוֹפָר בְּמַדְבְּרָא, מַאן יָהֵיב לָךְ עִגּוּלָא בְּמַדְבְּרָא. מִן דַּהֲוָה חָמֵי הַהִיא עַקְתָא דַּהֲוָה עָקֵי לֵיהּ, הֲוָה אָמַר בָּרוּךְ אֵל עוֹלָם שֶׁאָכַלְנוּ מִשֶּׁלּוֹ, הֲדָא הוּא דִכְתִיב לְכַתְּחִלָּה צְדָקָה וּלְבַסּוֹף מִשְׁפָּט. (בראשית יח, יט): לְמַעַן הָבִיא ה' עַל אַבְרָהָם וגו', תָּנֵי רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן יוֹחָאי אוֹמֵר, כָּל מִי שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ בֵּן יָגֵעַ בַּתּוֹרָה כְּאִלּוּ לֹא מֵת, שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: לְמַעַן הָבִיא ה' עַל אַבְרָהָם אֵת אֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר אֵלָיו לֹא נֶאֱמַר, אֶלָּא אֵת אֲשֶׁר דִּבֶּר ה' עָלָיו.

Translation from [here](https://www.chabad.org/parshah/in-depth/plainBody_cdo/AID/2545):

> When Abraham’s guests wished to bless him for his
>   generosity, he would say to them: “Has the food you have
>   eaten been provided by myself? You should thank, praise
>   and bless He who spoke the world into being!” If they
>   refused Abraham would demand payment for the food they
>   had eaten. “How much do I owe you?” they would ask. “A
>   jug of wine is one furlin,” Abraham would say; “a pound
>   of meat, one furlin; a loaf of bread, one furlin.” When the
>   guest would protest these exorbitant prices, Abraham
>   would counter: “Who supplies you with wine in the middle
>   of the desert? Who supplies you with meat in the desert?
>   Who supplies you with bread in the desert?” When the
>   guest would realize the predicament he was in he would
>   relent and proclaim: “Blessed be the G-d of the world,
>   from whose providence we have eaten.” (Midrash Rabbah;
>   Tosofot Shantz on Sotah 10)