# Is the mitzvah of accepting guest even when charging

Tags: halacha, mitzvah, money, hachnasat-orchim-guests

From this question   [Is it sourced that Avrohom Avinu charged his guests payment if they did not make a Brachah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/96503/5120) and from the fact that Rivka after serving Eliyezer got paid for it,
It seems that the mitzvah of accepting guest is to have room for someone who needs,
 **and that charging for the room and board does not diminish from the mitzvah**

Does someone say this idea?
Is it wrong?

Sources please.

Comment: Why does it seem like it doesn't diminish from the mitzva

Comment: @DoubleAA since he fulfills this mitzvah anyway, the mitzvah of giving free food it a separate one

Comment: @hazoriz What’s wrong with saying that one fulfills the mitzvah, but not the ideal form of it?

Comment: @DonielF nothing, but sources on this will be nice

Comment: I asked the original question on the other thread with the intention of leading up to a similar question as yours, which I have now posted here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96516/how-do-we-know-avraham-avinu-personified-gemilas-chasodim

Comment: *Hachnosat orchim* I believe is a "generic" term. If one owns a hotel and charges customers, he's still providing services to the guests such as lodging, food, and other amenties. I would think that the fact that your place is available for a traveler and you're providing this service - those items alone are fulfilling the mitzvah whether one pays for them or not.

Comment: @DanF very nice source please

Comment: See a source in the link listed ^^^.

Comment: @Yehuda see previous comment, maybe there is chesed even when payed, for example we there is the institution of tipping (the tip is for the amound of chesed that was done more then what was payed for))

Comment: There are multiple reasons for tipping. It could be a reciprocal. Frequently people tip the owner with the expectation that they be treated better next time esp. if they are a frequent patron. It's not necessarily a payment for the "extra chessed". Likewise, you could argue that the owner may do an extra favor solely for the purpose of the tip. I don't think that's considered a "chessed".